# Can I update multiple documents with different field values at once?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of 280,000 documents in elasticsearch.  I need to assign unique field values for each document.  Currently I am iterating through all ID values and updating each document using _update.  This process works fine but is very slow taking around 8 hours for 280,000 documents.

Any ideas on how I could speed this process up?  Is it possible to update multiple documents at once assigning different field values to each document.

Comment: Use [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) using which you can update multiple document in a single request.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ES Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), which will allow you to update multiple documents with single request.
I would suggest to check the [refresh property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) on the index as well, if you refresh the index every time you insert a record the performance will go down and I think that is whats happening to you just now. But if you use bulk update that should be fine, jsut something to keep in mind.

Comment: I'll try bulk update.  Does refresh occur every time I change a field value for a document?

Comment: You can set refresh property to a small value or a big value. It depends how quick you want your documents (values) to be available. The smaller the value + super often updates = poor performance, hence use the bulk update.